# Infinite Loop when setting setState hook as class attribute in Effect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an Effect hook in a React component that sets up and initialises a class that I use to communicate with a backend server:

```js
const SignalProvider = ({url, children}) => {
  let [sigErr, setSigErr] = useState("")
  let [token, setToken] = useContext(TokenContext)
  let [signaller, setSignaller] = useState()


  useEffect(() => {
    if (!signaller) {
      const s = new Signaller(url, (err) => setSigErr(err))
      setSignaller(s)
    }

    if (token && signaller) {
      signaller.setToken(token)
      signaller.setSetTokenCallback(setToken) // Adding this line causes an infinite loop
      signaller.connect()
    }

  }, [url, token, signaller, setToken, authError]) 

  ...
}
```

However, adding the line `signaller.setSetTokenCallback(setToken)` causes an infinite loop of re-rendering. Without this line it works as expected.

All `setSetTokenCallback` does is:

```js
setTokenCallback(f) {
  this.setTokenCallback = f
}
```

Which I don't think should matter.

Whats the best way to prevent the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using 'useCallback()' hook?

```
const initializeClass = useCallback(() => {
  if (!signaller) {
    const s = new Signaller(url, (err) => setSigErr(err))
    setSignaller(s)
  }

  if (token && signaller) {
    signaller.setToken(token)
    signaller.setSetTokenCallback(setToken) 
    signaller.connect()
  }, [url, token, signaller, setToken, authError])

  useEffect(() => {
    initializeClass()
  }, [bla bla all dependencies needed])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your culprit is in these lines

```
signaller.setToken(token) // first possible culprit
signaller.setSetTokenCallback(setToken)
```

Since you are setting the token inside the `useEffect` and your `useEffect` depends on the `token` value for a re-evaluation again. If the `token` value is different than the previous one then it will make the `useEffect` to re-render.

```
[url, token, signaller, setToken, authError] // second possible culprit
```

Also, you should remove object or array type variables from the condition array `[url, token, signaller, setToken, authError]` or stringify them or find some way to compare, as objects and arrays can't be compared directly. They will always return false if directly compared. Thus, your `useEffect` will re-run.

Comment: Yeah I think my main problem was having `signaller` as a dependency - which is an object